# Checkbox filter. (need assistance with function logic)

Tags: javascript, html

I asked a similar question here yesterday and was able to proceed further with the answer given, but ran into another problem I've been stuck trying to figure out.

**Current functionality:** If you click on a checkbox it will correctly change the background of the parent div to red, if it contains the correspondent selected checkbox/class. If you unselect *all* checkboxes it returns to blue.

**Issue:** If you select more than one box, and then unselect it, it's not correctly reverting the unselected box to blue after you've unchecked it. That only happens when *all* boxes are unchecked.

---

**Q:** How would I go about programming it so that when you unselect a box, it right away reverts the correct divs back to blue?

---

https://jsfiddle.net/ptxsha6m/11/

(Strangely, this code with only 'item' without the '.parentElement' works. 
Could anyone also clarify why that happens to me?)

```
<script>
var theID = document.querySelectorAll('#result1, #result2, #result3');

function change(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var chekboxInputs = Array.from(checkboxes).map(a => a.querySelector('input'));
    var allAreUnselected = chekboxInputs.every(function(elem){
       return !elem.checked;
    });
    if(allAreUnselected){
       chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item){
              item.style.display = 'block';
                            item.parentElement.style.background = "blue";
          });
       });
    }
    else {
      chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
          Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item){
            if(item.style.display = input.checked) {
                item.style.display = 'block';
              item.parentElement.style.background = 'red';
            } else {
                item.style.display = 'none';
            }
          });
       });
    }
}
change();
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, right now, the only code you have in here that is turning things blue is this section:

```
if(allAreUnselected){
   chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item){
          item.style.display = 'block';
                        item.parentElement.style.background = "blue";
      });
   });
}
```

So the ONLY time things are being turned `"blue"` is when `allAreUnselected` is `true`.

When one or more checkboxes are still checked, the logic is handled by this block

```
  chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item){
        if(item.style.display = input.checked) {
            item.style.display = 'block';
          item.parentElement.style.background = 'red';
        } else {
            item.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
   });
```

So it loops over each checkbox and, if they're checked, changes the color of their connected div to red.  The problem is, we can't just say "if it's checked go red / if it's unchecked go blue" because that will overwrite the last checked one.

I might be rambling a bit, sorry, I'm trying to talk through the problem a bit.  So, here's the easiest way to solve this problem.

Instead of setting everything to blue when you clear it, ALWAYS set everything to blue as the first step.  Then loop through and mark things red if they've been checked.

For example:

```
var theID = document.querySelectorAll('#result1, #result2, #result3');

function change(){
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var chekboxInputs = Array.from(checkboxes).map(a => a.querySelector('input'));
    var allAreUnselected = chekboxInputs.every(function(elem){
       return !elem.checked;
    });
  chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item){
      item.style.display = 'block';
      item.parentElement.style.background = "blue";
    });
  });
  chekboxInputs.forEach(function(input){
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("." + input.getAttribute("rel"))).forEach(function(item){
      if(item.style.display = input.checked) {
        item.style.display = 'block';
        item.parentElement.style.background = 'red';
      } else {
        item.style.display = 'none';
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I definitely think there are probably other/better ways to solve your problem, but this uses the code you've already written with only a minor change to do what you're asking, I think.

So each time the function is called - everything is set to BLUE and then anything that needs to be set to RED based on the checked boxes is set to red.  The setting to blue then red is sufficiently quick that there is no flicker - the code runs before any changes occur on the screen.

Comment: Really appreciate both yours and Jeff's answers, I was able to do it now. I knew something was wrong with the loop logic. Thank you for your explanation!